# Bootstrap navbar - how to make navbar-header full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How can make the navbar-header full width or a row on its own?

I added `clear:both;` on `collapse navbar-collapse` but all the padding are messed up.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="navbar-header" style="border: 4px solid red !important;">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <!-- navbar-header -->

            <!-- email -->
            <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
                email: <a href="#">xxx{at}example.com</a>
            </div>
            <!-- email -->

            <!-- collapse content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="border: 2px solid blue; clear:both;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="work.html">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CV</a></li>
                </ul>


                <div class="pull-right">
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- collapse content -->

        </div>

</nav>
```

Result:

[image]

The word **Brand** should be align with the word **Home**. Is it possible? What is the proper way doing in Bootstrap?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: if you remove those `borders`, it will be [just fine](http://www.bootply.com/ESFgOwTG98).

Comment: the result you shown is not what i want. please read my question properly.

Comment: Bootstrap navbar have 30px while header only 15px padding-left in total. Perhaps if you simple add 15px margin-left to navbar-header it will work ? It is what are you looking for ?

Comment: Sorry, misread your OP. [I believe this is what you are looking for](http://www.bootply.com/7uM8tmj5ou).

Comment: @Ganga then it has a an issue when it is on smaller screen. see my edit above.

Comment: @Vucko it's ok. i have tried that too. it has the problem when it is on smaller screen. see my edit above. same as adding margin-left 30px

Comment: Then simple add @media screen and (max-width: 768px) and set margin to 0 again. It should do the trick.

Comment: @Ganga that's what i am doing now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19469/). Use `media query` and reset the `padding` for the smaller screens:

```
.navbar-brand{
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
     .navbar-brand{
        padding: 15px;
    }  
}
```

[Bootstrap documentation for it's media querys](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Answer (score 1):

You can simple add margin to `.navbar-header` and then use `media screen` to modify it on smaller device's.  Here is code:

```
.navbar-header {
  margin-left: 15px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header {
    margin-left: -15px !important;
  }
}
```

Here is codepen with example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqjKpg